# Duplicating target in Xcode 4: update icons and splash screen and change plist file name?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

We duplicated a target in Xcode 4, but we are stuck on these issues:

1) The new plist file now says "X copy-Info.plist" where "X" is the original target name. How can we change the name to something like "X Premium-Info.plist?" We tried just changing the filename and updating the appropriate property under "Build Settings," but that failed.

2) The new target shows the same icons and splash on the "Summary" screen, but when we run the new target on the phone, the icons and splash screen do not appear and instead show the default icons and splash screen. Is this because the new plist file is not in the same parent folder as the "Icons" folder for the original target? How can we update the splash screen and icons for the new target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Delete reference of "x copy.plist" in project, change the file name in Finder manually, add to project again and change `Info.plist File` value under "Build Settings". It works for me.

Q2: This is because the new target can't find the correct Info.plist, after Q1 setting, change `CFBundleIconFile` and `UILaunchImageFile` in the new plist.

Good luck.